.net MAUI open pdf document with pdfjs from Application Data Directory in iOS
I'm having trouble opening a pdf document in a .net MAUI iOS app: the pdf files in question are downloaded and saved in the AppData Directory so i can't put them in the app bundle.
I load the pdf files in a WebView and setting the source as the absolute path of the pdf works fine, but i need to view it with pdfjs to have the toolbar.
My problem seems to be in the url i put as source of the webview/ the file path i give viewer.html in the pdfjs folder (which is in the app bundle).
The following code is the webview in the page.xaml
<Grid Margin="8">
    <WebView x:Name="newPdfView" Navigating="newPdfView_Navigating" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#fafafa" Grid.Row="1">
    </WebView>
</Grid>

The following code is what i have in the constructor:
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("newPdfView", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
            handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
#else

if (handler.PlatformView is WebKit.WKWebView wkWebView) 
{                         wkWebView.Configuration.Preferences.SetValueForKey(Foundation.NSObject.FromObject(true), (Foundation.NSString)"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs");
}
                    
#endif
        });
#if IOS
        var pdfFilePath = Foundation.NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("pdfjs/web/viewer", "html");
        var testPdfPath = Foundation.NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("test", "pdf");
        string path = $"file://{pdfFilePath}?file=file://{Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "Cataloghi", pdf.Descrizione + ".pdf")}";
        //path=$"file://{pdfFilePath}?file=file://{testPdfPath}"; This works with a test pdf in Resources/Raw
        newPdfView.Source = new UrlWebViewSource{ Url=path};
#elif ANDROID
        newPdfView.Source = $"file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=file:{WebUtility.UrlEncode(Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "Cataloghi", pdf.Descrizione + ".pdf"))}";
#endif

With an asset file it works fine but with a file in the Appdata directory the pdf doesn't load and shows the pdfjs toolbar and an empty document.
I tried changing the path around but nothing seems to load the document.
In Android it works with no problem.
